# Trouble in Rails 3 Adding Restful Routes to Namespaced Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, routes

I am trying to add a route to a controller that has been set as a resource in the 'admin' namespace like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :books do
    collection do
      post :process_new
    end
  end
end
```

I have added an action int the Admin::BooksController for process_new, but whenever I try to access this action using the url: .../admin/books/process_new I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Book with ID=process_new
```

It looks like it's routing to the show action and trying to use process_new as the id.  Can someone shed some light on what I may be doing wrong?

**Edit:
I changed my redirects to use the helper functions and it seems to be working.

Comment: Are you trying to access it manually in your browser? If yes,the error message is normal: your `process_new` route is only defined for post requests

Answer (score 0):

Add `get :process_new` to your resources :books routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :books do
    collection do
      get :process_new
      post :process_new
    end
  end
end
```